# How do I loop trough a list of strings and decrease the looping speed at the same time in js?

Tags: javascript, loops, delay

I want to create a javascript that loops trough all names and always displays the current name of the loop in the UI (html). But at the same time the loop-speed should decrease.

So lets say we start at a time of 10 loops / second. It should then decrease until its 1 loop / second and then stop at that point and display the name. Its kind of a raffle and the winner should be random.

So I created the script below but the problem is that nothing happens? Somehow just nothing happens. It executes the code but no errors and nothing changes in the UI. ***The code does get executed (tested it by logging to console)!***

My function:

```
function Roll(){
    var delay = 100;
    for(var i = 0; delay < 1000; i++){
        delay += 25;
        if(i >= listOfParticipants.length){
            i = 0;
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("person_name").value = listOfParticipants[i];
        }, delay);
    }
}
```

the html element:

```
<h1 class="text-center mt-2" id="person_name" ></h1>
```

EDIT:
I think I know what the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it. I think the for loop doesnt wait for the setTimeout to finish. Don't know how to handle it.

EDIT 2:
It seems that setTimeout creates a new ExecutionContext. That means the for-loop ends and gets its max value (13) before the setTimeout gets executed. The question now is how do I add a timeout in the current ExecutionContext?
*The list has only 12 objects thats why the result with i = 13 is undefined.*

Comment: replace `document.getElementById("person_name").value` with `document.getElementById("person_name").innerHTML` to view result

Comment: okay thanks. This solved the displaying problem. At least it shows undefined now. Read Edit 2 for more information.

Comment: Which name do you want to stop on? The last name in the array?

Comment: Just a random one. It doesn't matter but your answer worked for me. Just needed to change a few things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to stop on the last name of the array (since it wasn't clear in your question how name selection should work), there is a strategy that you can use.

Basically, instead of looping through your duration, you want to **loop through your array of `listOfParticipants`**. At each iteration, we decrease the duration that we wait before continuing on to the next iteration of the for loop.

```
// Pseudo code!
async function roll() {
  for (let i = 0; i < listOfParticipants.length; i++) {
    // Wait for promise to resolve
    await someKindOfPromise();

    // Update name
    document.getElementById('person_name').innerText = listOfParticipants[i];
  }
}
```

This can be done using **async/await**. The native for loop in ES6 supports awaiting for a promise, so we simply create a method that returns a promise that resolves after `x` number of seconds:

```
// A simple promise that resolves after a specified duration
function wait(duration) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    window.setTimeout(resolve, duration);
  });
}
```

After `x` number of second passes, we move on to the next iteration.

The value of `x` can be simply be determined by decrementing a pre-set duration based on our relative position along the participants array. The further you are in the array (indicated by the index `i`), the shorter you want the time to be, i.e.: `delay * i / listOfParticipants.length;`

```
async function roll() {
  const delay = 100;
  for (let i = 0; i < listOfParticipants.length; i++) {
    // Force the for loop to wait for a set amount of time
    const duration = delay * i / listOfParticipants.length;
    await wait(duration);

    // Once the duration has been awaited, we can then update the inner text
    document.getElementById('person_name').innerText = listOfParticipants[i];
  }
}
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const listOfParticipants = ['Adena', 'Socorro', 'Germaine', 'Ebony', 'Raul', 'Anton', 'Rochel', 'Morgan', 'Joanie', 'Ellsworth', 'Edelmira', 'Susannah', 'Gino', 'Vicenta', 'Katrina', 'Devorah', 'Olinda', 'Lise', 'Napoleon', 'Dessie', 'Herta', 'Cassaundra', 'Nadine', 'Dalton', 'Mica', 'Haydee', 'Linh', 'Williemae', 'Desiree', 'Philomena', 'Julio', 'Darell', 'Shana', 'Ligia', 'Melita', 'Laurene', 'Darby', 'Gregg', 'Shemika', 'Tesha', 'Benita', 'Hyman', 'Kattie', 'Mary', 'Julienne', 'Claud', 'Heather', 'Toney', 'Vasiliki', 'Stephani', 'Violette', 'Barney', 'Warren', 'Felix', 'Mathew', 'Blair', 'Jamar', 'Grover', 'Bud', 'Barbie', 'Gina'];

// A simple promise that resolves after a specified duration
function wait(duration) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    window.setTimeout(resolve, duration);
  });
}

async function roll() {
  const delay = 100;
  for (let i = 0; i < listOfParticipants.length; i++) {
    // Force the for loop to wait for a set amount of time
    const duration = delay * i / listOfParticipants.length;
    await wait(duration);
    
    // Once the duration has been awaited, we can then update the inner text
    document.getElementById('person_name').innerText = listOfParticipants[i];
  }
}

document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', () => roll());
```

```html
<h1 class="text-center mt-2" id="person_name"></h1>
<button id="btn">Raffle</button>
```

Comment: This works! Thank you! The "wait" is what I needed instead of the setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a loop you can call `setTimeout()` recursively:

```html
<h1 class="text-center mt-2" id="person_name" ></h1>
```

```js
var listOfParticipants = [
  "Kurt",
  "Dave",
  "Krist",
  "Alanis",
  "Aimee",
  "Chris",
  "Eddie",
  "Mike",
  "Stone",
  "Jeff",
  "Matt",
  "Boom"
]

function doIt(i) {
  var participant = listOfParticipants[i];
  if (!participant) return;

  document.getElementById("person_name").innerHTML = participant;
  setTimeout(
    function() { 
      doIt(i + 1);
    }, 
    100 + i * 100
  );
}

doIt(0);
```